# Check if mongoDB is connected

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have mongoDB in my app.

I want to check if mongoDB is connected, before I listen to the app.

Is it the best way for doing it?

This is my server.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoDb = require('./mongoDb');
var app = express();

init();

function init() {
    if (mongoDb.isConnected()) {
      app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1');
    }
    else {
      console.log('error');
    }
}
```

`isConnected` runs `getDbObject`. 
`getDbObject` connects to mongoDB and returns an object:
 connected (true/false), db (dbObject or error).

Then, `isConnected` resolve/reject by connected property.

This is mongoDb.js file:

```
//lets require/import the mongodb native drivers.
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
// Connection URL. This is where your mongodb server is running.
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myDb';

var connectingDb; // promise

//We need to work with "MongoClient" interface in order to connect to a mongodb server.
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

init();

module.exports = {
    isConnected: isConnected
}

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
function init() {
  connectingDb = new Promise(
    function (resolve, reject) {
      MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
          reject(err);
        }
        else {
          console.log('Connection established to', url);

          //Close connection
          //db.close();
          resolve(db);
        }
      });

    }
  );
}

function getDbObject() {
  return connectingDb().then(myDb => {
                                       return {
                                          connected: true,
                                          db: myDb
                                        }
                                      }
                              )
                       .catch(err =>  {
                                        return {
                                          connected: false,
                                          db: err
                                        }
                                      }
                             )
}

function isConnected() {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
          var obj = getDbObject();
          if (obj.connected == true) {
            console.log('success');
            resolve(true);
          }
          else {
            console.log('error');
            reject(false);
          }
        }
    )

}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: `isConnected()` is deprecated and was recently removed.  _"**Remove MongoClient.isConnected** - calling connect is a no-op if already connected"_ -- https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4.0/docs/CHANGES_4.0.0.md#removed-deprecations

Comment: @DemPilafian - was it replaced by something else? I've been looking and am coming up empty handed.

Comment: At the link Dem specified (GitHub link)[https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/4.0/docs/CHANGES_4.0.0.md#removed-deprecations] it says that calling `connect` is a 'no-op' ('no operation' I believe) if you are already connected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

there are multiple ways depends on how your DB is configured. for a standalone (single) instance. You can use something like this

```
Db.connect(configuration.url(), function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
```

if you have a shared environment with config servers and multiple shards you can use

```
db.serverConfig.isConnected()
```

Comment: This is not true anymore from 4.0, now connect() is a noop in case an existing connection is present.

Answer (score 12):

Let `client` be the object returned from MongoClient.connect:

```
let MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
let client = await MongoClient.connect(url ...
...
```

This is how i check my connection status:

```
function isConnected() {
  return !!client && !!client.topology && client.topology.isConnected()
}
```

This works for version 3.1.1 of the driver.
Found it [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/5744fc29eae5bcc9ca72ca7dfb428bf719c95e33/test/functional/sharding_connection_tests.js).

Comment: This returns true, but if I try to `insertOne` in a collection, I get `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed`. I'd like to test for this as well.

Comment: This does not work when using `useUnifiedTopology: true` when connecting, it will always return true

Answer (score 10):

There has been some changes since version 3, [`isConnected` is no longer available in version 4](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/HEAD/etc/notes/CHANGES_4.0.0.md#removed-deprecations). **The correct way of dealing with an ambiguous connection is to just call `MongoClient.connect()` again.** If you're already connected nothing will happen, it is a NOOP or no-operation, and if there *is not* already a connection you'll be connected (as expected). That said, if you really want to know if you have a connection try something like this:

```js
const isConnected = async (db) => {

    if (!db) {
        return false;
    }

    let res;

    try {
        res = await db.admin().ping();
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }

    return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(res, 'ok') && res.ok === 1;
};
```

Answer (score 6):

From version 3.1 MongoClient class has isConnected method. See on https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html#isConnected

Example:

```
const mongoClient = new MongoClient(MONGO_URL);

async function init() {
  console.log(mongoClient.isConnected()); // false
  await mongoClient.connect();
  console.log(mongoClient.isConnected()); // true
}
init();
```

Comment: the `isConnected` method was deprecated in client version 3.7 https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.7/api/MongoClient.html

and removed in version 4.x https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/MongoClient.html